# See more logs in Heroku with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I have read that in order to see more logs I needed to add the following lines in my production.rb file:

```
 config.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
 config.log_level = :info
```

If I do this, my application crash with the following message:

```
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:8:in `size': No such file or directory - log/production.log (Errno::ENOENT)
```

So... What can I do to see more logs? Like the ones I see in development?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should try to use [Loggly Add-on](https://addons.heroku.com/loggly) instead? There is a free plan with one day retention.